# Алгоритмы, оценка сложности функции

Tags: алгоритм, функции, сложность

> Покажите, что для произвольной константы c > 0 функция g(n) = 1 + c + c^2 + ... + c^n есть
>
> ```
> (а) Θ(1), если с < 1;  
> (b) Θ(n), если c = 1;  
> (c) Θ(c^n), если c > 1.
> ```
>
> Другими словами, в сумме убывающей геометрической прогрессии можно оставить лишь первый член; возрастающей - последний, а постоянной - количество членов.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чего начать? Есть ли какой-то универсальный метод для всех трех случаев?

Comment: вероятно вам надо почитать про пределы (Lim)

Comment: Артём тут простая геометрическая прогрессия есть формула тупо подставить и вычислить. Пределов не надо

Comment: @AzizUmarov автору нужна оценка сложности. Она имеет смысл при n -> бесконечность, что, по сути, является пределом.

Comment: Нет не согласен с тобой, какой предел у f(n) = n? его нет, а оценка есть

Comment: Скажу больше если есть предел то оценка O(1), так как предел это число.

Comment: @AzizUmarov окей окей, сдаюсь )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ничего сложного нет просто подставьте значения и подсчитайте что получится.
Имея
`g(n) = 1 + c + c^2 + ... + c^n` и формулу для суммы членов геометрической прогрессии [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Θ(1), если с < 1;

   Если считать `g(n)` бесконечной суммой, то можно применить формулу суммы бесконечной убывающей геометрической прогрессии

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   откуда имеем следующее,

   `g(n) = 1 + c + c^2 + ... + c^n < 1/(1-с) = O(1)` не зависит от `n`.
2. Θ(n), если c = 1;
   В этом случае подставив `c = 1`

   `g(n) = 1 + c + c^2 + ... + c^n = 1 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1 = 1 + n = O(n)`
3. Θ(c^n), если c > 1.

   Просто подставив в формулу суммы членов геометрической прогрессии

   `g(n) = 1 + c + c^2 + ... + c^n = (1-с^n)/(1-с) = (c^n -1)/(c-1) = c^n/(с-1) - const = const*c^n - const = O(с^n)`, где
   `const = 1/(с-1)`